# GRUB can't find Windows 10 after changing SATA cable entry

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have three SSD, two with linux (a 240Gb and a 480Gb), and one with Windows (a 480Gb).

I opened my desktop to clean it, and afterwards I mounted the SSds in different positions (probably).

Now, when I choose my windows installation from the Grub, it show the message

```
error: no such device: 1832-7ADF
error: disk 'hd4,gpt2' not found.
```

I can find the Windows dick using nautilus, the files are still there.
But neither `sudo os-prober` nor `sudo update grub` show my SSD Windows 10

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Have you tried reordering the cables to the other 8 possible combinations? It may end up easier than the technical fix.

Comment: Yes, I have tried, thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

So, after many tries I decided to go the hard way and reformatted the SSD and reinstalled windows.

Even after that, GRUB didn't recognized it.

So I went to Ubuntu and did `sudo os-prober` and `update-grub`.